# Add shadow in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am presenting a partial view controller from a modally presented view controller. I want to add a shadow layer below the partial view controller that covers the entire screen (except for the partial view controller), I can't quite figure out a way that can do this.

What I've tried:

- adding a UIView shadow on the modal view controller (Doesn't cover past the top of it's nav bar)
- adding a UIView shadow to key window (this covers the entire screen)

Is there a way to do this?

Here is where I add the view/child to the modally presented view controller:

```
func presentInfoVC() {
        vc.remove()
        vc = SlidingViewController()
        vc.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: vc.view.frame.maxY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1000)
        
        self.addChild(vc)
        self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
        vc.maximize(completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: It can be done, but without some code it's hard to help you out. Basically, you want to add a "shadow" to the presenting view controller, followed by showing the partially presented view controller - it's possible that this is actually the default behavior in iOS 15. Any chance you could post something more specific, maybe even some code?

Comment: Sounds more like you want a underlay of some sort, which sits above the previous view and under yours

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried that, but since the view controller below is presented modally the layer doesn't completely cover the screen

Comment: @dfd I added some code. thanks

Comment: What I usually do, is fake it.  So I use the `view` of the view controller as the background and the put another view on top of it.  Another solution might be to use a custom `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`

Comment: From what you say I guess you are using the default card-style modal presentation?  Are you able to change to a full screen modal as that would give you the real estate to fake the shadow with a UIView?

Comment: I am not sure if this is good idea, but I create quite complex shadows with CAShapeLayer. There is even shadowPath property to assist you with it. I used to for shadows of layers drawn with bezier path, but who knows, maybe this will help :)

Comment: @flanker unfortunately it cannot be .fullScreen